# Elasticsearch and IBM Mobilefirst shard warning

Tags: elasticsearch, ibm-mobilefirst

I am getting the following error in the logs:

```
[11:01:35,171][WARN ][org.elasticsearch.cluster.action.shard] [worklightNode_5585] [worklight__appsession__1467849600000][1] received shard failed for [worklight__appsession__1467849600000][1], node[Jnr7_ztjTBaV6_ItG9wf1Q], [P], s[INITIALIZING], unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2018-07-05T09:01:35.100Z], details[shard failure [failed recovery][IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[worklight__appsession__1467849600000][1] failed to recover shard]; nested: TranslogCorruptedException[translog corruption while reading from stream]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No version type match [53]]; ]]], indexUUID [HoE0oONmSQqvik0cUaFubA], reason [shard failure [failed recovery][IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[worklight__appsession__1467849600000][1] failed to recover shard]; nested: TranslogCorruptedException[translog corruption while reading from stream]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No version type match [53]]; ]]
[11:01:35,177][WARN ][org.elasticsearch.indices.cluster] [worklightNode_5585] [[worklight__device][3]] marking and sending shard failed due to [failed recovery]
org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException: [worklight__device][3] failed to recover shard
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:297)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$1.run(IndexShardGatewayService.java:112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.translog.TranslogCorruptedException: translog corruption while reading from stream
        at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.ChecksummedTranslogStream.read(ChecksummedTranslogStream.java:72)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:267)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to read [Device][d92a7a77-aa32-33ec-85b9-bfd85811714c]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.Translog$Index.readFrom(Translog.java:522)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.ChecksummedTranslogStream.read(ChecksummedTranslogStream.java:68)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: No version type match [103]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.VersionType.fromValue(VersionType.java:307)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.Translog$Index.readFrom(Translog.java:519)
        ... 6 more
```

Can somebody please explain what this warning means?

Comment: Did you do some changes after which you started noticing this error?

Comment: This is suspected to be a problem caused because of the tranlog corruption. Clearing the tranlog/temp directories located with the analyticsData (ES data) within the indices data should solve the problem. Please make sure the Analytics Cluster/servers are stopped while doing the same.

Comment: We could solve this by deleting the index files of the analytics cluster